# find UserControl's ParentForm during load

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to find a UserControl's ParentForm so I can hook some event handlers to it.  I tried doing this in a ParentChanged event handler on the UserControl, eg:

```
ParentChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  ParentForm.SomeEvent += ...
}
```

And this works fine if the UserControl's Parent happens to be the form.  However, if the UserControl is embedded in a container control (in this case a SplitContainer), the UserControl gets added to the container control before the container control gets added to the top level form's controls (as controlled in the InitializeComponent method).  That is, `InitializeComponent()` builds up the hierarchy from the leaves on up, so the leaves have no idea what form they'll eventually be placed on during construction.

So the ParentForm is null on the UserControl when the ParentChanged event is fired, and I don't get a ParentChanged event when the UserControl's parent's parent changes.  I could add listeners for the parent's ParentChanged event, but I'd have to do so on up the entire control hierarchy which isn't particularly elegant.

I'd basically like to get notified of when the ParentForm changes for a UserControl.  However there's no such event.  I could hook in to things like the Load event, however [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.load(v=vs.110).aspx) says it can get fired every time a control is shown if it's in a MDI container.  That MSDN article suggests putting things in the constructor, but that's what I'm doing right now and it's not working out because of the timing for when things get initialized.

Any ideas?

Comment: One possibility would be to invert dependency. Parent form can subscribe your control to own event (e.g. passing it via public callback of `UserControl`). Can you share details for what this event is used, what are you going to do in `UserControl`, etc.?

Comment: Would `myUserControl.FindForm()` give you what you want?

Comment: @Sinatr - The control is a window I draw DirectX calls to.  I'm trying to get maximize/restore, resize, move, and mouse events from the parent form for a bunch of different things, eg: mouse wheel zoom as long as the mouse is over the control, regardless of whether the control has focus.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - It would if the parent control (or its parent, or its parent's parent, etc.) had been added to the top level form yet.  But as I describe in my post, InitializeComponent() creates controls from the leaves on up, so FindForm() is just returning null during its ctor, and even waiting until the ParentChanged event doesn't help because the parent hasn't been added to the form yet.

Answer (score -1):

I needed this too in my own customcontrol.
I subclassed a button and in the onclick I need to know the form.
So the trick is actually not getting the form in the load but getting it at the time you need it.

This worked for me :

```
private Form GetParentForm(Control parent)
{
    Form Result = parent as Form;
    if (Result == null)
    {
        if (parent != null)
        {
            // Recursive is cool
            return GetParentForm(parent.Parent);
        }
    }
    return Result;
}
```

I use it like this

```
protected override void OnClick(EvnetArgs e)
{
    Form form = GetParentForm(Parent);
    if (form != null)
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: This does basically what FindForm does, right?  As I describe in my post, the problem is actually that the parent form hasn't been set yet during either the ctor or the ParentChanged event, and MSDN says the Load event might not be a good place for this sort of logic because of how it handles MDI children.

Comment: that is why i said that the trick is to get the form when you need it, not when loading the control. I dont remember the details anymore but I had troubles with findform method and made this little method in stead, dont remember what it was anymore

Comment: I remember that FindForm had troubles when the usercontrol is on an inherited mdi form. For some dark reason it returned null while my method does not which is strange because they basically do the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to add event handlers to the form, so it's not as simple as just finding it when I need it.